# $\text{Let $A$, $B$, and $X$ be sets. Prove that if } A\subset B \text{, then } X\setminus B \subset X\setminus A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove the following lemma regarding elementary set theory: $$\text{Let $A$, $B$, and $X$ be sets. Prove that if } A\subset B \text{, then } X\setminus B \subset X\setminus A$$

I am currently working with the definitions of the various operations used in this proof. Specifically, I have that for all x, $$A\subset B\implies  \text{ if }x\in A \text{, then } x\in B $$ $$X\setminus B\implies x\in X \text{ and } x\notin B $$ $$X\setminus A\implies x\in X \text{ and } x\notin A$$

Any help in working toward this solution is appreciated!

Comment: Suppose $x\notin B$. Then since everything in $A$ is in $B$ ...

Comment: "If $x \in A$, then $x \in B$" is an if-then statement. Any such statement has a logically equivalent contrapositive statement.

Comment: Take any element $x\in X\setminus B$, then $x\notin B$, and since $A\subset B$, it follows that $x\notin A$ and therefore $x\in X\setminus A$.

Comment: ahhh that makes sense. I was trying to prove it supposing $A \subset B$ and going from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For two sets $C, D$, here's how you show $C \subset D$: if $x \in C$, then $x \in D$.

You **want** to show $X \setminus B \subset X \setminus A$.

Suppose $x \in X \setminus B$. Then, as you stated, $x \in X$ and $x \notin B$. But note that $A \subset B$. Since $A \subset B$, it follows that $x \notin A$ because $A$ is contained in $B$ (if $x \notin B$, there's no way that $x \in A$ due to $A \subset B$, so it must be the case that $x \notin A$). Hence, $x \in X$ and $x \notin A$. By definition, this means $x \in X \setminus A$.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thank you!